# How to minimize powershell form after button click?

Tags: powershell

It doesn't matter if it is hidden or if it is minimized I just don't want it to be viewable to the user.

Pertinent Code:

```
$Login_Load={

}
$buttonENTER_Click = {
    $newuser = $username.Text
    $newpass = $password.Text
    GoTo_Run $newpass $newuser
}
```

Things I have tried:
I have used the Set-WindowState Cmdlet but that hasn't worked for me either.

`(Get-Process -Name processnameofform).MainWindowHandle | foreach {Set-WindowStyle FORCEMINIMIZE $_}`

`$Login.Hide`

`$Login.WindowState("Minimize")`

Comment: Any reason you're not prompting with `Get-Credential`?  It's purpose built for requesting user names and passwords.

Comment: The users don't like the look of the `Get-Credential` screen, so we had to remake our own login screen and pass the values into that screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FormWindowState is an enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Assuming that $Login is your Form:

```
$Login.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Minimized
```

or

```
$Login.WindowState = 1
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't have that one piece of knowledge about that syntax!